# Google maps should fit at least 3 nearest markers to your current location point, by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a button that should redirect you to your current position on map, but after redirecting to position map should be zoomed automatically, and you should be able to see at least 3 nearest markers.

This is a part of my code. The only thing it does it's just fit bound to all markers, but doesn't show my location

```
 $('a.geolocation').click(function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      for (var i=0; i<storeLocator.markers.length; i++) {
          if(storeLocator.markers[i].getVisible()) {
              bounds.extend( storeLocator.markers[i].getPosition() );
          }
      }
      map.setCenter(pos);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is this.  You set the map's centre to the user's position.  But then you make the map fit the bounds of your stores, which will adjust the map's centre, and not necessarily keep your user's position visible.

All you need to do is make sure that position is also in the bounds.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude
    );

    bounds.extend(pos);

    for (var i=0; i<storeLocator.markers.length; i++) {
        if(storeLocator.markers[i].getVisible()) {
            bounds.extend( storeLocator.markers[i].getPosition() );
        }
    }

    map.setCenter(pos);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```